# Connecting to Oracle database with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oracle

I want to connect to Oracle database through JavaScript code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
    <title>Connecting to Oracle using JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        var conObj = new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Connection');

        var connectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(CID=GTU_APP)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.119.132.175)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));User Id=mdm;Password=admin;"

        conObj.Open(connectionString);
        var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
        sql = "SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL"

        rs.Open(sql, conObj);
        alert(rs(0));
        rs.close;
        conObj.close;
        //-->
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am getting ActiveXObject is not defined error
ActiveXObject doesn't work for chrome browser it seems!

Comment: ActiveXObjects are basically deprecated. Those won't work (reliably) any more on modern browsers.

Comment: Yeah, i came to know that. is there any solution  to connect with database through javascript?

Comment: With only JavaScript? I doubt it.

Comment: Yes,Mr.Cerbrus! I only want it with JavaScript. Actually the thing is i am creating a Chatbot with DialogFlow in javascript and I want to display the count of records in chatbot.

Comment: Set up [Oracle REST data services](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/rest.html) and connect to that.

Comment: Are you really putting an full connection details including username and password into a script that is going to be sent your users?

Comment: Yeah i know its not secured.  But i need to give a Demo by the month end, so trying with all the possible ways. And its being a month i started learining and working on javascript. Excuse me for my mistakes! pls share your suggestions..

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues to take into account

- You need a driver in the client to deal with a database
- Since you want to connect from client your credentials must be present in client side.
- Your database port and url must be accessible from a browser

All of those issues implies that **your database will be completely exposed to anyone**.

To avoid some of the risks, in my opinion the best approach (if you still want to avoid server code) is using web services provided by oracle. There are several examples in oracle docs using SOAP and REST, [here an example using REST](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r51/restful_web_services/restful_web_services.html). Once you have the resource created, you call that resource using ajax. To prevent the restriction made by browser when you attempt to perform a cross origin ajax, you should set a [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header in the database server. In this way you could access to the database without server code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect directly from the browser, but you can connect using javascript in NodeJS, using the npm module "oracledb".  I have been using it in production for about 3 years now -- it works really well.

Comment: Hi Nick, I was trying to connect to an oracle instance using nodejs code and followed foll steps: download and unzip instant client, set the path in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, installed node-oracledb, wrote test connection code and ran it, however, I am not able to connect to the database. The request is timing out without any error. Are there any more steps according to you to connect to oracle from linux machine with nodejs?